# SQL Server agent failing: loop in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I am daily running a SQL Server Agent Job, which contains a ssis-project with a loop, which tries to do a task, but max 3 times. So it happens, that the task needs 2 tries, this is totally fine. But the SQL Server Agents gives back the information, that the Joob failed, but it didn't. It only should say "fail", when the the Loop fails 3 times. Any suggestions how to do it?

Kind regards,

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to make a try catch... retry. You can consider using a script task to do this. This is an example for an email sending task but it could be anything. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576097/implement-send-mail-task-with-multiple-tries-in-case-if-its-failed-to-send-mail/59581372?noredirect=1#comment105421601_59581372

Comment: I do not have the skills to change the Execute Process Task to a script task

Comment: that's an easy one... https://www.dotnetperls.com/process

Answer (score 0):

```
Change the setting of the  MaximumErrorCount  to 3
```

Comment: It is at 100, to make sure the loop works, but it doesn't help with the problem

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your ssis package?

Comment: Changed the precedence constraints from Fail to Completion. In order to avoid error and re-run the task again

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to upload the error messages given in the Failed Execution Report for that package?